# How do I use relative paths for PHP includes?

Tags: php

I'm having trouble learning relative paths for PHP includes.

Trying to get an include statement in index.php to find footer.php in the includes folder in _assets two folders up.

From what I read here on SO, I would think it would be:

```
include('../../_assets/includes/footer.php');
```

I'd rather use an absolute path, but can't get that to work either.

---

Figured out the absolute URL path.

```
echo file_get_contents('http://www.mysite.com/_assets/includes/footer.php');
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: The relative path from your index.php is as you guessed `../../_assets/includes/footer.php`, I don't see why that shouldn't work? Try using `echo getcwd();` in your index.php to see the current working directory.

Comment: **WHOA**.  Do *not* echo *local* files by fetching their URLs.  You are dispatching an unnecessary HTTP request.  That's silly at best and a *tremendous* waste of time and resources at worst.

Comment: @Charles, Thanks for your input. I knew it wasn't the most efficient way to do things. I'm a novice and was surprised it even worked, thought echo was used to display text. The site is a bit confusing, basically 3 sites in one and I need a central folder for all the CSS and Include files and a good way to link to them from all over the site and also be able to have the site work locally and on the server. Can you suggest and better method?

Answer (score 2):

To use an absolute path I would suggest you define a constant which points to your document root, e.g.:

```
define('PATH_SITE', '/path/to/www/');
```

Or on Windows:

```
define('PATH_SITE', 'C:\\path\\to\\www\\');
```

Subsequently you use that path to get the proper include:

```
include_once(PATH_SITE . 'assets/whatever.php');
```

Alternatively you can use the built-in PHP Variable `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but I've seen it being flaky on Windows servers

Comment: so do I put the define in a php file in the root folder?

Comment: You put it in the file where you start the first include from (maybe `index.php`) so it will be available on all subsequent includes